# Curl while loop with 2 variables within shell

Tags: shell, curl

### Objective

I'm trying to create a loop that will use my logins, select an account based on `column 1`and then select the platform based on `column 2`of `input.csv`. I have assigned each column to it's own variable in the hopes that it will loop through each row together and pull the reports i need, instead of me having to make a super long script of copy and paste.

---

input.csv

```
729352,7
355543,7
461432,7
```

---

Current Code

```
#! bin/sh

set -eu

value1=$(awk -F"," -v OFS=',' '{ print $1 }' input.csv)
value2=$(awk -F"," -v OFS=',' '{ print $2 }' input.csv)

rm -f cookiejar
curl  /dev/null -s -S -L -f -c cookiejar 'https://url/auth/authenticate' -d name=usr -d passwd='pwrd'

while IFS="," read -r value1 value2 remainder
do

curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar 'https://url/auth/adminaccounts' -d account=$value1
curl -s -S -L -f -O -J -b cookiejar -c cookiejar "https://url/report/ajax-by-tag2?platform_id[]=$value2&id1=&id2=&id3=&id4=&id5=&id11=&id12=&id13=&date=2019-11-25&date_start=&date_end=&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=1&zfDetails=false&by_viewability=imps_givt&device_id[]=all&tag_type_id[]=all&support_id[]=all&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx"

done < "input.csv"
```

Current Error

> +curl -o /dev/null -s -S -L -f -b cookiejar -c cookiejar https://urlauth/adminaccounts -d account=729352
>
> &id1=&id2=&id3=&id4=&id5=&id11=&id12=&id13=&date=2019-11-25&date_start=&date_end=&website=&zfTablePage=1&zfTableColumn=&zfTableOrder=desc&zfTableQuickSearch=&zfTableItemPerPage=100&zfTableDataTablesMaxRows=1&zfDetails=false&by_viewability=imps_givt&device_id[]=all&tag_type_id[]=all&support_id[]=all&zfTableItemPerPage=10000&zfTableExport=xlsx
>
> curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

### What I have tried

- I have replaced variable 2 in the url with the value "7" and can confirm that it loops through column 1 pulling each file.
- I can confirm that variable 2 populates "7" correctly if I changed it with variable 1 (though it obviously doesn't download anything as it's not an account).
- I've tried doing various different quote options around the url but every time it spits out the error above.
- I've tried to put brackets around the variable `{$value2}`which I found worked when I used variables in the url previously.
- Reviewing online, there is a lot of talk about the error being caused by different parts of the url, but I know the issue lies with the variable as it works without it. Can someone tell me what I seem to be missing to get this to work correctly?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but using `set -e` is... [not necessarily a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises). (There are also [caveats to `set -u`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/112), but much more reasonable ones).

Comment: BTW, what's the purpose of the `awk` commands? Anything they put in `value1` or `value2` is replaced by `read` before the variable is ever used.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the purpose of the awk commands is because I've only been teaching myself shell for the last few weeks and I couldn't think of a better way to do it XD. Just tried removing the `awk` and I can see it works without it. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Ahh. FYI, a great resource is the Wooledge wiki; [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) goes into detail on correct usage of `while read`.

Comment: ...what I suspect is that your original file probably has DOS newlines, so the last field is always read as having a `$'\r'` on the end. That explains the log file starting a line in the middle (right after `value2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to not having a `,` after each line in the csv. So the input needed to be:

```
729352,7,
355543,7,
461432,7,
```

Comment: ...that said, I can't reproduce this behavior at all. `read -r a b r <<<'a,b'; echo "$?"` emits exit status `0`, meaning success, so the body would run. Can you speak to which specific shell you were testing with in producing this issue?

Comment: ...also, see https://ideone.com/u1X6rd, showing your original code working perfectly without needing the trailing commas to be added.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on windows. Thanks for all the helpful documentation!

Comment: "On Windows" is pertinent -- almost certainly, then, your input file is in Windows format and has CRLF newlines instead of LF-only newlines (as UNIX tools expect). One change you can make to work around that is to change `IFS=,` to `IFS=$',\r'`.

Comment: ...alternately, you could just use `dos2unix` to convert the file, or open it in vim, run `:set fileformat=unix` and save, etc.

Comment: ...anyhow, what adding the final `,`s is doing here is making the carriage return before the linefeed in the text file go into the `remainder` variable instead of being in `value2` where it gets passed to `curl`.

Comment: (BTW, see the *very first entry* in the "before asking about problematic code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for bringing this to my attention. I didn't realise there were these kinds of differences between the 2 systems. I'll aim to be more conscious of this in the future.